# Function for duplicate rows

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like below:

```
> df
     pat_id disease
[1,] "pat1" "dis1" 
[2,] "pat1" "dis1" 
[3,] "pat2" "dis0" 
[4,] "pat2" "dis5" 
[5,] "pat3" "dis2" 
[6,] "pat3" "dis2"
```

How can I write a function to get a third variable which indicates for the same pat_id the disease variable is the same or not , like below?

```
> df
     pat_id disease var3
[1,] "pat1" "dis1"  "1" 
[2,] "pat1" "dis1"  "1" 
[3,] "pat2" "dis0"  "0" 
[4,] "pat2" "dis5"  "0" 
[5,] "pat3" "dis2"  "1" 
[6,] "pat3" "dis2"  "1"
```

Comment: `as.integer(duplicated(dat) | duplicated(dat, fromLast = TRUE))` might work,

Comment: You don't have a dataframe. That was a matrix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `ave()` for the groupings, and wrap the result from `any(duplicated())`, with `as.integer()`. Then bind with `cbind()`.  Although I might recommend you use a data frame instead of a matrix here.

```
cbind(
    df, 
    var3 = ave(df[,2], df[,1], FUN = function(x) as.integer(any(duplicated(x)))
)
#      pat_id disease var3
# [1,] "pat1" "dis1"  "1" 
# [2,] "pat1" "dis1"  "1" 
# [3,] "pat2" "dis0"  "0" 
# [4,] "pat2" "dis5"  "0" 
# [5,] "pat3" "dis2"  "1" 
# [6,] "pat3" "dis2"  "1"
```

For larger data, I would recommend converting to a data table.  The syntax is actually a bit nicer too, and it will likely be faster.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt[, var3 := if(any(duplicated(disease))) 1 else 0, by = pat_id]
```

which gives

```
   pat_id disease var3
1:   pat1    dis1    1
2:   pat1    dis1    1
3:   pat2    dis0    0
4:   pat2    dis5    0
5:   pat3    dis2    1
6:   pat3    dis2    1
```

where column classes will be more appropriate (char, char, int).  Or you could use `as.integer(any(duplicated(disease)))` instead of `if`/`else`.

Comment: Also, `as.integer(ave(df[,"disease"], df[,"pat_id"], FUN=anyDuplicated) > 0)` as a variation on a theme,

Comment: I also have triple pat_id rows, how can i modify the syntax?

Comment: how can i modify it to show if the disease is the same for the 3 or more rows with the same pat_id?

Comment: @trillian - This will work for any number of the same pat_id

Answer (score 1):

Slightly long-winded, but gives you a boolean third variable which is more easily tested. It also doesn't care about data types

```
> df <- data.frame(pat_id=c("pat1","pat1", "pat2", "pat2", "pat3", "pat3"), 
+                  disease=c("dis1","dis1","dis0","dis5","dis2","dis2"), 
+                  stringsAsFactors = F)
> counts<-apply(table(df), 1, function(x) sum(x!=0))
> df2<-data.frame(pat_id=names(counts), all_the_same=(counts==1))
> df3<-merge(df,df2)
> df3
  pat_id disease all_the_same
1   pat1    dis1         TRUE
2   pat1    dis1         TRUE
3   pat2    dis0        FALSE
4   pat2    dis5        FALSE
5   pat3    dis2         TRUE
6   pat3    dis2         TRUE
> sapply(df3, class)
      pat_id      disease all_the_same 
 "character"  "character"    "logical"
```

This doesn't care how many of each combination you have and should leave your strings as strings - not factors.

Having the new column as a logical lets you more easily do queries such as finding all patients for which it is true

```
> unique(df3$pat_id[df3$all_the_same])
[1] "pat1" "pat3"
```

Answer (score 1):

One option using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
as.data.frame(df) %>%
     group_by(pat_id) %>%
     mutate(var3 = as.integer(n_distinct(disease)==1))
#  pat_id disease  var3
#   (chr)   (chr) (int)
#1   pat1    dis1     1
#2   pat1    dis1     1
#3   pat2    dis0     0
#4   pat2    dis5     0
#5   pat3    dis2     1
#6   pat3    dis2     1
```